# What is the difference between it and describe in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

Thank in Advance, 
Can anyone give the advantages of Rspec?. Why the client wants Rspec testing. What are all the benefits?.

Explain me what is `it` and `descibe` below

```js
class ClassRoom 
   def initialize(students) 
      @students = students 
   End
   
   def list_student_names 
      @students.map(&:name).join(',') 
   end 
end 

describe ClassRoom do 
   it 'the list_student_names method should work correctly' do 
      student1 = double('student') 
      student2 = double('student') 
      
      allow(student1).to receive(:name) { 'John Smith'}
      allow(student2).to receive(:name) { 'Jill Smith'} 
      
      cr = ClassRoom.new [student1,student2]
      expect(cr.list_student_names).to eq('John Smith,Jill Smith') 
   end 
end
```

Comment: A simple google search doesn't give anything ? you should ask what are the benefits of TDD

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I googled it. I got the benefits of the developers. But i cant get the end user advantages.

Comment: One of the reason they ask for it is, developers/vendors  change, client doesn't :) TDD/BDD helps them for future, Also since you are asking about rails, we use a lot of gems, which could break something in future, if we upgrade them, TDD would let you know about that instantly. Its not only about development, but also about future maintenance and enhancement which might be done by some other developer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the general pros and cons of a software development process (test driven development).

Comment: Ok @spickermann Thank you, Thanks to all for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Test Driven Development - writing a test case that fails before writing code to pass the test - leads to code that strongly resists bugs, is easy to change, and has a very low rate of defects released to production. Like the commenters said; look it up.

End users get a stable product with a steadily increasing feature set. If they request a new feature, the turnaround time to using it can be very short.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..

Comment: If you have a client requesting automated testing - congrats - and can you ask _them_ what they think the benefits are and report them here?

Comment: Clients asking for Rspec, what happened to developers providing added TDD/BDD advantages in SOW :)

Comment: Close all you want @spickermann, but programmers should do TDD even if their Statement of Work does not request it. There are simply no "cons" about it!